Difference between change in momentum caused by a force and by kinetic energy
I don't see what the difference is between a momentum change caused by a force (eg: someone pushing against a metal ball) and and by transmission of kinetic energy (eg: a metal ball hitting another metal ball at rest).
The trouble i'm having is that i don't see how these isolated cases glue together.
I'm really looking for a professional answer.
Thanks in advance.

$$\frac{\mathrm d\vec p}{\mathrm dt}=\vec F=-\vec{\nabla\mathcal H}$$

These are two sides of the same coin. In order for something to change kinetic energy, a force must act over some distance to produce work.

When the net-impulse is perpendicular to the momentum,
the net-work done is zero...so the kinetic energy is not changed.
$$dK= \vec v \cdot d\vec p$$

Update, to say this another way:
While all net-impulses change the momentum vector, not all net-impulses change the magnitude of the momentum vector. Those that do change the magnitude are also associated with changes in the kinetic energy.

You don't see a difference because there is no difference. It's just different ways to describe the same phenomenon. Both descriptions are equally valid, but may be quite different in the resulting math's complexity, depending on the situation.
You can describe the two-balls situation also from a "forces" point of view: when the first ball initially touches the second one, both start to deform due to the (small) elasticity of the material, and this deformation produces a (spring-like) force pushing at both balls. So, the first ball pushes against the second one, accelerating it, and at the same time the second ball pushes back against the first one, decelerating it. This continues (more or less) until both balls have recovered to their original form.
As it's hard to calculate the deformation-force relationship and the resulting force profile over the impact duration, in this case the kinetic-energy approach results in much easier mathematics.
In the case of someone pushing against a ball (with a constant force), there's no mathematical difficulty in calculating the momentum change from the product of force and time. Calculating from the kinetic-energy point of view isn't much harder in this case (product of force and path length), but not as straightforward.

When two balls hit they exchange a morsel of momentum called impulse. How the impulse affects kinetic energy is secondary.
The primary mechanism is Newton's 3rd law, where an equal and opposite quantity of momentum (force over time) is exchanged between the two objects during a contact.
$$\begin{aligned}
\Delta \vec{p}_1 & = \mbox{-}\vec{J} \\
\Delta \vec{p}_2 & = \mbox{+}\vec{J} \\
\end{aligned}$$
where $\Delta \vec{p}_i$ is the change in momentum (vector) for each body, and $\vec{J}$ is the impulse (vector).
To relate (change) in momentum and motion, use Newton's 2nd law as it applies to each body separately.
$$\begin{aligned}
 \Delta \vec{p}_1 &= m_1 \Delta \vec{v}_1 \\
 \Delta \vec{p}_2 &= m_2 \Delta \vec{v}_2 
\end{aligned}$$
where $m_i$ is the mass of each body, and $\Delta \vec{v}_i$ the change in motion of each body.
The last part you need to handle impacts is the law of collisions which relates the relative speed of the two bodies before and after the impact.
The relative speed is resolved along the contact normal direction $\hat{n}$ which is used also to decompose the impulse vector into a direction and magnitude $\vec{J} = J\,\hat{n}$.
The impact speed (relative speed before contact) is defined with the following projection
$$ v_{\rm imp} = \hat{n} \cdot \left( \vec{v}_1 - \vec{v}_2 \right) $$
and the bounce speed (relative speed after conact) is defined using the changes in velocities
$$ v_{\rm bounce} = \hat{n} \cdot \left( (\vec{v}_1 + \Delta \vec{v}_1) - (\vec{v}_2 +\Delta \vec{v}_2) \right) $$
where $\cdot$ is the vector dot poduct.
The law of collisions relates the above with
$$\boxed{ v_{\rm bounce} = - \epsilon \; v_{\rm imp} } $$
where $\epsilon$ is the coefficient of restitution.
If you combine all of the above you will find that
$$ J = (1+\epsilon) \left( \frac{m_1 m_2}{m_1 + m_2} \right) v_{\rm imp} $$
and the thing in the parenthesis is the reduced mass of the system.
